# linq query and foreign used to create data

Tags: c#, linq, foreign-keys

I got problem facing the problem that i am using the table, "locationstation" and create station and location inside and both the station and location were linked to locationstation by their primary key. I have already successfully showed their data in the combo box but the problem now is that i don't know how to select the data inside the combo box and save the data in the locationstation table.

```
 private void btnCreate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            //station selectStation = cbStation.SelectedItem as station;
            //location selectLocation = cbLocation.SelectedItem as location;

            string selectStation = cbStation.SelectedItem.ToString();
            string selectLocation = cbLocation.SelectedItem.ToString();
            locationstation creLS = new locationstation();
            creLS.idStation = cbStation.SelectedItem.ToString();
            selectLocation.Location1 = (string)cbLocation.SelectedItem;
            Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(selectStation);
            //Setupctx.SaveChanges();
            //cbStation.SelectedIndex = -1;
            //cbLocation.SelectedIndex = -1;

            MessageBox.Show("New Location Station Is Created");
        }
    }
```

I don't how to make it working but my codes that i'm trying is right here. Help will be greatly appreciated.

This is the code that i bind the station name and location name into the combo box.

```
private void Create_LS_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (testEntities Setupctx = new testEntities())
        {
            var storeStation = (from SLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                                        join station s in Setupctx.stations on SLS.idStation equals s.idstations
                               select s.Station1).Distinct().ToList();                                   
            foreach (var LocationStation in storeStation)
            {
                cbStation.Items.Add(LocationStation);
            }

            var storeLocation = (from SLS in Setupctx.locationstations
                                join location l in Setupctx.locations on SLS.idLocation equals l.idlocation
                                select l.Location1).Distinct().ToList();                                      
            foreach (var LocationStation1 in storeLocation)
            {
                cbLocation.Items.Add(LocationStation1);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi set all Navigation properties of selectStation equal to null before Adding the the object using

```
Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(selectStation);
```

instead of

string selectStation = cbStation.SelectedItem.ToString();

use

LocationStation selectStation=(LocationStation)cbStation.SelectedItem;

and then extract values from selectStation or do what you want with it.
I hope this will help.

Comment: I somehow knows where the problem were but i do not know how to code it out. The table locationstation has column of stationid and locationid but my combo box contains the station name and location name. Somehow they were not the same. Any idea how? i think my code above abit screw up.

Comment: althought there's no error on the codes but they prompt me a error message while i select the station and location from the combo box. The error they showed me is "Unable to cast objects of type "System.String" to type "Setups.locationstation"."

Comment: What is the type of List that you are binding to the ComboBox

Comment: The station and location names but i used their primary keys to link with the table locationstation

Answer (score 0):

```
Station selectStation = (Station)cbStation.SelectedItem ; //cast here to your T
Location selectLocation = (Location)cbLocation.SelectedItem; //cast here to your T

locationstation creLS = new locationstation() 
{
 StationId=selectStation.Id ,
 LocationId=selectLocation.Id
};

Setupctx.locationstations.AddObject(creLS);
Setupctx.SaveChanges();
```

However I can not imagine doing something like above on the combobox with Key/Value data.
because probably binding lookup types comboboxes to KeyValuePair by using .ToDictionary()
(where T is type of primary key) opens up easier code reuse  to handle
selected items and bindings on any combobox in whole app by setting ValueMember = Key
and DisplayMember =Value (or whatever Key/Value properties are in your combo control) then you can do this for example:

```
long GetSelectedId(comboBox cbo)
{


long IdOut=-1;

if (cbo.SelectedItem==null)
return IdOut;

KeyValuePair<long, string> Item= (KeyValuePair<long, string>)cbo.SelectedItem;
IdOut   = Item.Key;

return IdOut;

}
```

Comment: I don't quite understand about the second code that you gave but it confirm cannot work on my case. whereas, your first code given on top shows the same error as the previous answer. Any idea?

Comment: try setting ValueMember and  DisplayMember and bind those using DataSource property: combobox.datasource=YourLinqQuery, I mean instead of foreach and Items.Add

Comment: But i was advised to use linq.